# If $m^*(E)$ > $0$ then there exists a bounded subset $K$ of $E$ s.t $m^*(K) > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $m^*(E)$ > $0$ then there exists a bounded subset $K$ of $E$ s.t $m^*(K) > 0$

Since $m^*(E)$ = inf{$\sum_{k=1} ^\infty l(I_k) | E \subset \cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$} s.t $I_k$ :open sets.

Set $\cup_{k=n}^\infty I_k$

Then for some m, $\cup_{k=m}^\infty I_k$ $\subset E$

Set K=$\cup_{k=m}^\infty I_k$ then it is done.

Did I prove appropriately? If not, what is worng?

Comment: Is $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä $\mathbb{R}^1$

Comment: Ah... after I wrote this, I have noticed that I didnt show K is bounded...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$\mathbb{R}^d = \bigcup \limits_{n=1}^\infty B(0,n),$$
we have
$$E= \bigcup \limits_{n=1}^\infty \left( B(0,n) \cap E \right),$$
and by countable subadditivity of $m^*$
$$m^*(E) \leq \sum \limits_{i=1}^\infty m^*(B(0,n) \cap E ).$$
Since $m^*(E) > 0$, an element of the series has to be nonzero. This element corresponds to a bounded subset of $E$ that has nonzero measure.

Comment: What does B represents?

Comment: Its a ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$: $B(x,r) = \left\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^d \: \middle| \: \left\| x- y \right\| < r \right\}$.

Comment: It seems like subset of E is E...right?

But what if K is a proper subset of E? such K exists?

Comment: Clearly $B(0,n) \cap E \subset E$. However, you also have that $B(0,n) \cap E \subset B(0,n)$, thus $B(0,n) \cap E$ is a **bounded** subset of $E$; it is in the ball $B(0,n)$. What you need to show is that for some $n > 0$, the measure $m^*(E \cap B(0,n))$ is strictly positive. I prove this in my answer.